# How to start music after 10 second is remaining on timer in Android Studio using JAVA

Tags: java, android-studio

So I made one minute countdown timer. Basically I want to start music(10seconds long) after 10 second is remaining on timer with `SoundPool`. This is my code so far:

```
public class BeginAfter extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int tensec;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_after);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(1)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();
        soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        tensec = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.timer_run, 1);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        long duration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

        new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String sDuration = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%01d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)));
                textView.setText(sDuration);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BeginAfter.this, Begindup.class);{
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: You have the function `onTick` for your timer. I think checking there to see if there are 10 seconds left, and if that's the case playing the music would work

Comment: I'm beginner and this code is copied and pasted. I don't know what does what. code would be helpful if you can❤

Comment: Let me see what I can do

Comment: Can you please refer me to where you took the code from?

Comment: I think from youtube but do not remember which video specifically.  But here's [something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69223682/simple-countdown-in-android-studio-using-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This seems right to me. Please note that you are defining soundPool twice. I'm not an expert, but that seems unnecessary to me. Judging by what I found online, you only have to write the second definition in case your API level is lower than android lollipop.
[This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/soundpool-in-android-with-examples/) is where I saw the definitions.

```java
public class BeginAfter extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int tensec;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_after);
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setMaxStreams(1)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .build();
        soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0); // this seems very unnecessary to me, as you are defining soundPool the line above.
        tensec = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.timer_run, 1);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        long duration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

        new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String sDuration = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%01d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)));
                textView.setText(sDuration);
                if (l / 1000 == 50){
                    soundPool.play(tensec, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                soundPool.release();
                Intent intent = new Intent(BeginAfter.this, Begindup.class);{
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Here's a solution using MediaPlayer

```java
public class BeginAfter extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_begin_after);
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.timer_run);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.timer);

        long duration = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);

        new CountDownTimer(duration, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                String sDuration = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%01d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(l) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(l)));
                textView.setText(sDuration);
                if (l / 1000 == 50){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(BeginAfter.this, Begindup.class);{
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

Comment: It works thanks!!! But only problem is that audio is stopping after 6-7seconds! I know for sure that this audio is exactly 10seconds long

Comment: Does it start playing exactly after 50 seconds?

Comment: Did you try deleting the line I marked as unnecessary?

Comment: No it starts exactly after 10 seconds. But after audio is started, after 6or7 second later audio stops for no reason

Comment: Do you want it to start after 50 seconds or after 10 seconds? When does it start right now?

Comment: Also, please see the line I added (`soundPool.release()`). It's crucial

Comment: With your code it starts after 10 second but I changed 50 to 10. So it starts after 50 seconds

Comment: Okay that works. Add the line I added. I do not know what's causing the music to stop. Can you run your app on debug mode and see if any exceptions are thrown?

Comment: When starts it throws this: "createTrack_l(0): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST successful; frameCount 0 -> 262144"
But nothink when it stops

Comment: What exactly is the file's size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237422/discussion-between-gurami-supatashvili-and-alonkh2).